# Send notification to a particular UID using Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

I have a flutter food ordering app which contains "Orders" table in Firebase Realtime Database.  Here's the structure of the orders table.

```
orders/userId/oderId
```

[image]

I want to send a notification to a particular user via Firebase UID whenever any new order is created. I know the User UID of my admin user. I just don't know how to use this UID to send notification to this particular user.

Here's my code so far:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(); 
exports.myFunction = functions.database.instance("bb-9bb36")
    .ref("orders/{userId}/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {  
      console.log(snapshot.val());               // I can see the data submitted under Functions -> Logs
      console.log("Inside push notification");  //I can see this logs under Functions -> Logs
    });
```

Comment: There is a [sample Cloud Function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) about sending Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications, in the Cloud Function samples.

Comment: I see that it contains tokens. Is there a solution without using tokens? Just sending to a particular email address using that email addresses' UID?

Comment: So you want to send emails, not (Cloud Messaging) notifications?

Comment: My users login to the app using gmail. Every gmail account is associated with a UID generated by firebase. I want to send notification to one particular logged in user using their UID.

Comment: "I want to send notification"  => What do you exactly mean? Sending an email or sending a [Cloud Messaging notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)? Since we can send **notifications** with Firebase, it is not crystal clear what you want to do.

Comment: I want to send cloud messaging notification using cloud functions such that when a new order is submitted, a user with a particular UID should get the notification on their phone.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I meant, sending notification to a particular UID and not sending email to particular email. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do what you want,
you need to register a token from your client (client side) and save it to it's firestore document.

I dont know what you are using Front Side so I'll show you how I did that in ionic :

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

// ...
const token = await this.fcm.getToken();
```

and save that token as a field in your user document.

After that, in your Firebase Cloud Function, use :

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

async sendNotif(userId: string) {

const payload = {
    notification: {
      'the title of the notif',
      'the body of the notif',
      sound: 'default',
      click_action: 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY',
    },
    data: {
      command,
    },
  };
  const userSnap = await admin.firestore().collection('user').document(userId);
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userSnap.data().token, payload);
}
```

EDIT :
For Flutter you can use :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class MessageHandler extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessageHandlerState createState() => _MessageHandlerState();
}

class _MessageHandlerState extends State<MessageHandler> {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

    // TODO... (configuration for your project ...

}
```

and to get the token :

```
    // Get the token for this device
    String fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken();
```

Comment: I am using Dart.  Do you have an example using Dart?

Comment: it is exactly the same in the Cloud function. You just have to get a token from the Dart lib for firebase. There is a full tutorial on how to do it there : https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/

Comment: But how does a token relate to a particular user? Do I have to create a token for each user in my database?

Comment: i updated my answer. You have to get the token with String fcmToken = await _fcm.getToken(); and save the fcmToken into the user Document. After that when you will want to send a notification to that particular user, in your cloud function just retrieve the user document and use the token saved here

Comment: Am not sure if I am following. Do you have an example using firebase Realtime database that shows how the token is generated, saved, and retrieved for push notification?

Comment: yes ... the link i shared you just above is a total example

Comment: Based on the article, it seems like I have to create an entry of the users in firestore together with their token and then retrieve a particular token to send notification. This solution forces me to deal with an extra database. Isn't there an easier way to approach this?